# Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task Warning: Path must be a string. Received null Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

Running `grunt` is giving me this:

```
$ grunt 
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
Warning: Path must be a string. Received null Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

If it helps I've got:

```
jshint: {
  files: [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    '<%= paths.src %>/js/globals.js',
    '<%= paths.dist %>/js/**/*.js',
    '<%= paths.src %>/test/**/*Spec.js'
  ],
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe in your `options` you have set `reporterOutput: null`. You could try setting it to an empty string: `reporterOutput: ""`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2922#issuecomment-219263558)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/666

You probably just need to bump `grunt-contrib-jshint` to `0.11.1` or newer :)